# How do I tell pdb.run to use my current imports when running from a shell?

Tags: python, pdb

I want to start a pdb session from the Python shell on a function using `pdb.run()`.
I know that I can give it a `globals` or a `locals` parameter, but I don't know what values to pass so that I keep all of my current imports in the debugger session.
`pdb.run('myfunction()')` doesn't seem to keep any previous imports I made in the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. You need to pass in the result of the `locals()` function:

```
pdb.run('myfunction()',locals())
```